# Is there a way to tell if a file is encrypted sufficient?

Tags: encryption

So I have this file backup software which claims that it has "encrypted" my backup with my chosen password. Is there a fast way to verify if the file is really sufficiently encrypted?

Comment: Define "sufficiently". "I want to feel safe" is not a definition. If you don't trust the backup software, don't use software where you can't check what encryption algorithm they use, and how safe it is.

Comment: Encrypted data should look random. Find software that judges the randomness of the file for a strong indication. If the contents of the file were not compressed to begin with, try compressing it and see if it does. If the compressed archive is significantly smaller then the original its not well encrypted (but this is not a guarantee it is well encrypted, just an indicator)

Comment: @ davidgo Thanks for the comments. I agree the question can be not precise enough, but I did want to gather professional opinions. I think I have just achieved that from your comments.

Comment: @dirkt thanks for the comment, this is good information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to do forensic examination of the backup results.

Use the backup software to backup one long text file, then dump all printable
strings in the file using any of the appropriate programs.
If you can see enough text then no encryption was done.

Try next to use any file-analyzing program to find the type of the backup file.
The first few characters of the file might be enough to identify it.
If this is Zip or similar, use the appropriate product to open it up and
examine if you can extract the file.

If the backup passes these tests, then it is encrypted enough to foil the
occasional hacker. This is sufficient, because no protection is enough against
a professional hacker.

Comment: I'd question this definition of "sufficient". At least define a proper threat model. And there's still a wide gap between "an output file passes your tests" and "an output file will be difficult enough to crack to keep professional hackers disinterested".

Comment: @dirkt: Neither the poster nor myself demanded protection against professional hackers.

Comment: The poster didn't define a threat model at all. Which is the crux of the problem.